# How do I display query results in multiple lists based on a field?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working through a simple problem that I feel I am over complicating. Getting query results with 3 fields, and wanting to display a column list for each type in a certain field.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY type";
# query results are name(string) , tag(string), type(string)
$users = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $users[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
                $users[$row['id']]['tag'] = $row['tag'];
                $users[$row['id']]['type'] = $row['type'];
            }
        }
```

I can get them into an array , but I can't figure out how to display them in lists separately by type.

```
IE:

| usera 1 Guest | userb 2 User | user3 3 Admin |

| userp 4 Guest |
```

So I have a grouped list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Comment: you need to clarify how output should look like.